# Where can I find a list of chinese characters and their transcription in the 5 stroke classes used in the 五笔画 (wǔ bǐhuà) and Wubixing input method?

Tags: mandarin, characters, stroke-order, database, strokes

For a personal project I want to create a (huge) graph that contains some (as many as possible) chinese characters along the paths of their corresponding keyboard input using the 5 stroke classes **horizontal**(一), **vertical** (丨), **left falling** (丿), **right falling/dot** (丶), and **turning** (乛/乙). I didn't have a problem to find a database that included a list of some thousand characters transcribed for their use in the Wubihua input method, but in this method only the 4 first strokes plus the last stroke is used, as opposed to a transcript of all the strokes building up that character.

For example, for 毓 you only type 丿一乛乛乛.

However, I am looking for a transcript like this:
果 = 丨乛一一一丨丿丶

The strokes used can be encoded in whatever way, I just need the full information. For example, I found an open source project for the Wubihua method (= exactly the 4+1 way I am *not* looking for) that encoded them like this:

`nmmn. 即
.mmm/ 許
m/nm/ 區
m/m., 報
/nmmm 量
m//mm 基
m/mm/ 打
m//mm 聯
m/n,n 西
.mmm/ 該
m/mmn 指`

with `.`, `/`, `,`, `n` and `m` representing the 5 stroke classes mentioned above. I've been searching in GitHub repos for hours, but was only able to find the short 4+1 strokes version used in Wubihua.

I would be very grateful for a hint or link to a free-to-use database containing the necessary information for, say, at least some hundred of the most frequent characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [zdic](http://www.zdic.net)? See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj1EL.png)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword to search for is **筆順編號**.

[This github respository](https://github.com/YQ-YSY/stroke-seq_MB/blob/master/text/%E5%8D%95%E5%AD%97_%E7%AC%94%E9%A1%BA%E7%A0%81_29685%E4%B8%AA.txt) contains stroke order sequences for 29685 characters, coded as numbers 1-5. From the readme:

> 仅仅以1、2、3、4、5五个数字分别代表“一丨丿丶”五个笔画，按汉字笔顺进行输入。例如：
>
> “开”字，按笔顺“一、一、丿、丨”，编码为1132； “我”字为31；“向”字为325；“力”为53；
> 注意“万”为153，“方”为4153，“忄”为442。
>
> **其中有些笔画容易被误解： “提”归为“一”：如“氵、扌”中的最后一笔**；有些电脑字体繁体字的“雨字头”四点显示为四小横，皆按国标笔顺归为四点；
>
> **“亅”一竖往左勾的归为“丨”：如“小”字的第一笔、“扌”提手旁等；“乚”一竖往右勾的归为“”：如“比、民、氏”的左边那一笔；**
>
> **“点、捺”都归为“丶”：如“文、入、表、厶”的最后一笔；“宀”宝盖头和“冖”秃宝盖的左边那一笔也都是“丶”，不是“丨”；**
>
> **各种折笔（乛、フ、乚、、⺄、竖弯钩、竖提等）都归为“”：如“为、孔、民”中的笔画。**

Bolded parts are easy to misinterpret strokes - but they've grouped it under the same 5 classifications as you've mentioned in the question details, so I guess this wasn't a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for!